# replace non Null values in column by 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that have a column that looks like:

```
note

129.0
130.0
131.0
132.0
133.0
134.0
135.0
136.0
137.0
138.0
139.0
140.0
141.0
142.0

143.0
```

So there are the rows that don't contain the values (NaN). 
I'de like to replace the numerical values that are not NaN by 1, to have:

```
note
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

1
```

I tried this code:

```
def replace():
    if  (pd.notnull(df['note'])):
        df['note'] = '1'
        return df
    return df
```

it returns me `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `loc` for this:

```
In [86]:
df.loc[df['note'].notnull(), 'note'] = 1
df

Out[86]:
    note
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      1
6      1
7      1
8      1
9      1
10     1
11     1
12     1
13     1
14     1
```

`if  (pd.notnull(df['note']))` won't work because `if` doesn't understand how to treat an array of boolean values hence the `ValueError` because you may have all -1 or only one `True` value in the boolean array

Comment: thank you for quick and correct answer as usual @EdChum!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `where` to achieve this as in an in-place operation.  It will set any values not matching a predicate to a specified value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'note': [145.0, np.NaN, 147.0]})
df.note.where(df.note.isnull(), 1, inplace=True)
```

Yields

```
In [14]: print(df)
Out[14]: 
   a  note
0  a     1
1  b   NaN
2  c     1
```