# Python best way to process specific Pandas DataDrame column if value not null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, nan

What's the best way to process values in a specific set of Dataframe columns only if it's not null?

my original code:

```
for i in columns_to_process:
    df[i] = df[i].astype(str) + '!'

#columns_to_process is a list of selected df column name strings
```

I realised that this will turn null values into `nan!` but I just want to keep them nulls.

I've looked into using `.apply()` and a `lambda` function but that's bad practice when working on individual columns apparently, according to: [Pandas: How can I use the apply() function for a single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34962104/pandas-how-can-i-use-the-apply-function-for-a-single-column) . Seems like `.apply()` is more for updating every column in the dataframe.

Then I came across this: [replace non Null values in column by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218719/replace-non-null-values-in-column-by-1) and managed to make this working solution:

```
for i in columns_to_process:
    df.loc[df[i].notnull(), i] = df.loc[df[i].notnull(), i].astype(str) + '!'
```

It took me a long time to figure this out and doesn't look very elegant, so I'm wondering if there is a better / more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, try `pandas.DataFrame.where`:

```
# Sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                            'two'],
                   'bar': ['A', 'B', np.nan, 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'baz': [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, 6],
                   'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't']})

columns_to_process = ['bar', 'baz']
df[columns_to_process] = df[columns_to_process].where(df[columns_to_process].isna(), lambda x: x.astype(str)+'!')
df
```

Output:

```
   bar    baz  foo zoo
0  A!!  1.0!!  one   x
1  B!!  2.0!!  one   y
2  NaN    NaN  one   z
3  A!!  4.0!!  two   q
4  B!!  5.0!!  two   w
5  C!!  6.0!!  two   t
```

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. But how would I apply this to specific columns only, instead of the whole DataFrame Like my example with `columns_to_process` above?

Comment: @RoryLM I've edited the answer. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Cheers for fast response. Works now I've made minor change (see edit). Do you know if `.where()` has much of an advantage over my original method with `.loc()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`DataFrame.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html)

```
df.astype(str).add('!').where(df.notnull())
#to fill NaN with the previous null values
#df.astype(str).add('!').where(df.notnull(),df)
```